# Apache PIG- set date of current row as next records date minus one day for a given id

Tags: apache-pig

I have requirement to set end_dt as next records effective_dt minus 1 day for a given id and default it to 9999-12-31 for last record of a given id in pig.

input data-

```
id     eff_dt      end_dt
1    2012-02-28   9999-12-31
1    2013-03-15   9999-12-31
1    2014-05-01   9999-12-31
```

Required result- (order by eff_dt and then get the next record)

```
id     eff_dt       end_dt
1    2012-02-28    2013-02-14
1    2013-03-15    2014-04-30
1    2014-05-01    9999-12-31
```

i am new to apache PIG, found that we can use lead/lag , stitch/flatten but not getting how to use it in the script to achieve above result .I am facing few issues.

```
Issue 1 :- PIG accepts date as chararray. Need to convert eff_dt into date.
Issue 2 :- want to know syntax for 'date minus 1 day'.
Issue 3 :- How to use lead lag to get next record and do a minus one day and default if there is no next record.
```

Got below sample code from apache pig site but not getting how to transform it to use it in my use case.:-

To find the record 3 ahead of the current record, using a window between the current row and 3 records ahead and a default value of 0.

```
 A = load 'T';
 B = group A by si;
 C = foreach B {
     C1 = order A by i;
     generate flatten(Stitch(C1, Over(C1.i, 'lead', 0, 3, 3, 0)));
 }
 D = foreach C generate s, $9;
```

This is equivalent to the SQL statement

select s, lead(i, 3, 0) over (partition by si order by i rows between current row and 3 following) over T;

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The ids should all be unique, isn't it ? And for the first expected result row, the end_dt should be 2013-03-14, not 2013-02-14

Comment: Yes it should be 2013-03-14. No id's are not unique. We need to do calculation for a given set of id. Please find below more appropriate sample data.                                                                                                      input data- 
          ------------
          id     eff_dt      end_dt
         1    2012-02-28   9999-12-31
         1    2013-03-15   9999-12-31
         1      2014-05-01   9999-12-31
         2    2010-01-10   9999-12-31
         2    2011-03-28   9999-12-31

Comment: You can edit your question, this will help to have a better formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 questions, to which I can only answer the first two at the moment:

How to convert yyyy-mm-dd into a date and substract a day:

```
dataB = FOREACH data { 
    date = ToDate(eff_dt, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    dayBefore = SubtractDuration(date, 'P1D');
    dayBeforeFormated = ToString(dayBefore, 'yyyy-MM-dd');

    GENERATE eff_dt, dayBeforeFormated;
}
```

I finally had a chance to try the Over and Stich method from piggybank. Here's a working solution.

```
-- first load the piggybank and define shorthand to Over and Stitch functions
REGISTER '/data/lib/piggybank-0.12.0.jar';
DEFINE Over org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Over();
DEFINE Stitch org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Stitch();

-- load the input data
data = LOAD '/data' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (id:int, eff_dt:chararray);

-- generate the previous date (that could be done later)
data_before = FOREACH data { 
    date = ToDate(eff_dt, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    dayBefore = SubtractDuration(date, 'P1D');
    eff_before = ToString(dayBefore, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    GENERATE id as id, eff_dt as eff_dt, eff_before as eff_before;
}

-- Stitch join two bags based on position
-- Over apply a function on a group. Here we use the lead operator to get the next tuple
data_over = FOREACH (GROUP data_before ALL) {
    out = Stitch(data_before, Over(data_before.eff_before, 'lead', 0, 1, 1, '9999-99-99'));
    GENERATE FLATTEN(out) as (id, eff_dt, eff_before, end_dt);
}

-- finally, we output (we could have transform the date here)
data_final = FOREACH data_over GENERATE id, eff_dt, end_dt;
```

The output of this script is :

```
(1,2012-02-28,2013-03-14)
(1,2013-03-15,2014-04-30)
(1,2014-05-01,9999-99-99)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was useful. Now i have dayBefore column for a given id. I need to know next row and pick its dayBefore column value and put it in my current row as end_dt.